# wpf attached property: where to unsubscribe from event handling?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, attached-properties, unsubscribe

I have a dependency property (bool) which enables a behavior in a textbox.
The property changed callback subscribes to some eventhandlers:

```
static void MyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is TextBox && e.NewValue != null)
        {
            var tb = d as TextBox;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                tb.Loaded += TextBox_OnLoaded;
                tb.MouseLeftButtonDown += TextBox_OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
            }
            else
            {
                tb.Loaded -= TextBox_OnLoaded;
                tb.MouseLeftButtonDown -= TextBox_OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
            }
        }
    }
```

in my Xaml, i have:

```
<TextBox
        customdp:MyTextBoxBehavior.EnableBehavior="True">
</TextBox>
```

Leaving this, the behavior works fine. But the unsubscribing never is executed!
So Where do I have to put:

```
customdp:MyTextBoxBehavior.EnableBehavior="False"
```

???

Here is another case:
2) I have a listview and subscribed inside OnLoaded() to events of sub items in the visual tree. Reason: I don't want to add attached properties to each listviewitem.

```
static void ListView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var lv = sender as ListView;
        if (lv != null)
        {
            foreach (TextBox tb in lv.Items)
            {
                 tb.LostFocus += TextBox_OnLostFocus;
            }
        }
    }
```

Idea: unsibscribe in:

```
ListView_OnUnLoaded(..)
{
   // Items already empty 
}
```

...where to unsubscribe ?

Comment: Why and when do you want to unsubscribe? The only reason which I can figure out is closing window?

Comment: The windows are inside a TabControl with 1..n Tabs, and can be dynamically created and closed. So I guess I need to unsubscribe for garbage collection.

Comment: So why won't you do unsubscribe when tab is closing?

Comment: i have no access to the tab closing code, it is in another module. The unsubscribe must be in the behavior. Therefore I try to catch events like "UnLoaded" that tell me the UIElement is going to get removed from the visual tree. In My case above, the child items, from which I want to unsubscribe, are already removed, and I can't remove the handler then.

Comment: I also use the Unloaded and works fine (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment where you are able to do `tb.Loaded +=` you also have access to `tb.Unloaded`. Use that opportunity to add your cleanup code which will unsubscribe the `Loaded` event -- and *also* the `Unloaded` event.